# Formatting Laptop before resale - Security

Tags: windows, laptop

I come to ask your opinion please:

I have a gaming PC that I no longer use. And since it is only 1 year old and in like new condition, I would like to resell it.

Knowing that I had personal data on it, what do you advise me to format it? And especially that nobody can recover my data behind?

My PC has Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 in dual-boot. But I want to resell it with Windows reset (as it was when it left the factory).

But above all I wish that no one could recover my data behind.

Do you have a Windows utility for me? Windows 10 has a "Reset this PC" tool. But I am not sure it is reliable ???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Secure erase](https://www.delkin.com/blog/understanding-secure-erase-features/#:~:text=Secure%20Erase%20is%20a%20feature,that%20data%20to%20be%20retrieved.) should work for you.

Comment: Don't secure erase an SSD.

Comment: Why are you downvoting everybody that tries helping you?

Comment: @harrymc This is a bad question and should be closed, but the answers are not great (and likely wrong).

Comment: @davidgo: Yes, I was the first to vote.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here, but a couple of thoughts - If this were a commercial environment most likely the ssd/HDD would be removed from the PC and physically destroyed. In your case a likely reasonable alternative would be to use a USB bootable Linux disk to overwrite the contents if the disk - for example using "shred -n1 /dev/sdX".  The limitation is that this won't overwrite a tiny amount of information arround damaged sectors if the disk has them. It is even worse for SSD, depending on how over provisioning has been set up - but it will make recovery of data hard....

Comment: To the point where you can't use standard tools to recover any data. (You could go to an expert and get chips removed and dumped and maybe or maybe not get fragments of data).  If you are hiding (regular) porn or activity considered a misdemeanor - this is likely good enough as the costs vsdtly outweigh the benefits.  If its where you dumped a body, I wouldn't risk it... For future reference, usecFull Disk Encryption (bitlocker/luks) from the start on your next system - and then you can quickly wipe data by just securely erasing the header block - which is quick and robust.

Comment: In *some cases* on some drives, secure erase will securely delete everything. There are faulty implementations though.  Note that after yoyvwipe the full disk you will likely want to reinstall Windows. Most name brand PCs have the keys embedded in the firmware. Aftermarket sales may require the key be saved prior to OS deletion, or might have a label with it.

Answer (score -1):

You're able to wipe the hard drive and installing a fresh copy of the OS on Windows 10 thanks to its built-in method.

Simply go to Start>Settings>Update & Security>Recovery and click Get Started and choose the applicable selection. In order to restore Windows 10 back to a pristine state, you will have to follow the set of instructions which can be found in the applicable selection you just clicked on. In this case, choose the Remove Everything option to, surprisingly, get rid of everything. If you have more than one drive on your laptop, you will be asked if you want files removed from all drives, and as a safety option, this is the best method.

Lastly, you will be asked if you want to clean the drives. This will take a few hours but will make sure that there are no files recoverable from the disk.